# Conditional expectation value

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation

A taxi company has $n$ cars each with two mirrors. Each mirror breaks off independently with probability $p$, let $D$ denote the number of cars that have lost both mirrors and $M$ the total number of broken mirrors.
Find:
$$
E(D|M=m) \quad  \text{where $m=0,...,2n$}
$$
So far I have tried to express:
$$
P(D=k|M=m)=\frac{P(D=k;M=m)}{P(M=m)}
=\frac{P(M=m|D=k)P(D=k)}{P(M=m)}
$$
Now here I'm stuck because I tried to express $P(M=m|D=k)$ as a sum but but I get very difficult expressions to simplify. And I can't really compute the sum for the expected value.

Comment: Can whoever down voted explain why you did? Maybe I can fix it.

Comment: Didn't down vote but my guess is that you provide no evidence that you attempted the question by yourself. Although people are willing to help and offer solutions to your question, its nice to see some attempt done by you, or work to show for it. Even if its just ideas

Comment: That will work, but will likely be complicated.

Comment: PS: If you were to persist, $(M-2k)\mid D=k$ will be binomially distributed, $\mathcal{Bin}(2n-2k, \frac{2p(1-p)}{1-p^2})$ so $$\mathsf P(M=m\mid D=k) = \binom{2(n-k)}{m-2k} \rho^{m-2k}(1-\rho)^{2n-m} \cdot\mathbf 1_{m\in\{2k, .., 2n\}}\qquad : \rho=\frac{2p(1-p)}{(1-p^2)}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find $\mathsf E(D\mid M=m)$

Hint: Use Indicator Random Variables and the Linearity of Expectation.

---

Spoilers: <s>Don't unwrap until Christmas.</s> No, peeking until you've tried it yourself.

---

> Let $D_i$ be the event that car $i$ has both mirrors broken, and $\mathbf 1_{D_i}$ the indicator random variable of that event.   (Meaning it has value $1$ when $D_i$ and $0$ otherwise.)

---

> Then by the linearity of expectation and the identical (conditional) distribution of the events : $$\begin{align}\mathsf E(D\mid M=m) & = \mathsf E(\sum_{i=1}^n\mathbf 1_{D_i}\mid M=m) \\ &= \sum_{i=1}^n\mathsf P(D_i\mid M=m)\\ &= n~\mathsf P(D_1\mid M=m)\end{align}$$

---

> So, what is the conditional probability that a particular car has both mirrors broken when given that $M$ of the $2n$ mirrors are broken?